# How to catch Pokemon... with a rod?

Tags: pokemon-uranium

I received an *Old Rod* from an NPC, but was never given instructions on how to use it. I worked out by standing near a bed of water, I can open my inventory and select the item, and *Use* it. I also realised it was easier to *Register* the item, so I could use it without opening by inventory.

However any time I stand near a bed of water and use the item (either from the inventory or my registered key, I suspect there should be no difference) I am greeted with a

> . . . . . . . .
>   Not even a nibble...

The amount of periods vary, and I've found I can press the *Action* key to cut it short (although I suspect that doesn't help). Every few attempts, I normally get a nibble, but the Pokémon escapes.

> . . .
>   Oh! A bite!
>   The Pokémon got away...

I played several of the original games on GameBoy (FWIW: Blue, Yellow and Silver) and don't recall having this many problems. I also recall that one only message I ever got in those previous games was

> . . . (3 dots)
>   Not even a nibble...

And one couldn't truncate the procedure.

---

I feel like my success rate is about 1/20. Is there some special way to catch Pokémon with a rod? Should I or should I not be using the *Action* key part-way through? Am I just at an unlucky bed of water? I've tried several nearby:

[image: Story of my life]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried hitting the action button immediately after seeing the "Oh! A bite!" message? In the first two generations, the fishing was either a yes or no and you didn't have to do anything, but after those generations, you had to hit a button to actually initiate the battle, otherwise the pokemon would get away after a few seconds.

I noticed the games you listed were all games that were released prior to this feature.

For the record, I haven't played Pokemon Uranium, but I'm suspecting that it works the same as in the canonical games.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer provided by Vemonus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/284334/130645) is completely correct for this game, and this is actually explained in game, although a little later than desired.

As you enter *Route 08 - Wheatfields*, there is a sign that reads the following:

> Trainer Tips!
>   When fishing, you need patience and quick reflexes. Wait until the message "Oh! A bite!" appears, then reel it in quick!

[image: Better late than never]

This at least ties in

> to where you receive a *Good Rod*, which allows you to catch better Pokémon.

It's worth noting that similar to the first generation games, you will eventually have the option to get a better rod which *appears* to have a better success rate (I don't have any proof, sorry)